# Scope of global variables in a Javascript class

Tags: javascript, jquery, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a custom Javascript object, that looks like this:

```
var CustomClass = function(settings) {

this.var_1 = false;
this.var_2 = null;
this.var_3 = 0;

}

CustomClass.prototype.method_1 = function(){

  var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function(cropWidget) {
      this.var_1 = true; 
    });
}

CustomClass.prototype.method_2 = function(){

console.log(this.var_1); // logs 'false' onto the console  
if(this.var_1)
 { // proceed further and do something
 }
}
```

The CustomObject is instantiated upon:

```
$(document).ready(function{;  
  var customObj = new CustomClass({/*json values*/});
});
```

And  then, another DOM event will call upon method_1 like:

```
$('#element1').click(function(){
   customObj.method_1(); // this is where var_1 is being set to true
});
```

The **problem happens, when method_2() is being invoked** in the DOM by another element, like this:

```
$('#element2').click(function(){
  customObj.method_2();
});
```

it **checks for the value of var_1** which as you would recall has been **set to true when customObj invoked method_1**

this.var_1 is false, and not true as it should be. Does this mean the scope of var_1 was set to true only for the scope of the method_1() and still retains it's older value? IMO Javascript is pass by reference, so that variable value should have been set to true in it's original place.

Can someone explain where I am going wrong and how I may go about setting the value of var_1 such that it retains it's new value in method_2 as well ?

Comment: Every time you click on `#element`, it makes a **new** `CustomClass` object.  My guess is that you are calling `method_2` on a new object, instead of the same one.

Comment: "another DOM event" - does that other handler also create a new instance?

Comment: Show us the code where you actually call `customObj.method_2()`

Comment: @RocketHazmat, my bad, the customObject is instantiated in document.ready().
everyone else: made some edits to the question. Thank you

Comment: Are those click handlers being bound *inside* the *same* `$(document).ready` handler?

Comment: @pimvdb, well no, by another DOM event I mean events such as click and they do not instantiate the customObject again

Comment: @RocketHazmat yeah man, inside the same document.ready handler

Comment: @ParijatKalia: Then it should work, because it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bre7t/

Comment: As @RocketHazmat just beat me too it, it works for me too. There's some details you're not telling us. Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TcKWt/) that actually recreates your problem.

Comment: hmmm, thanks for the fiddle, I probably need to really revisit my code after this..

Comment: umm..I guess, give me a few, it's HUGGGEEE CODE!

Comment: OK guys, here is what's happening, the this.var_2 is being set to true in method_1 alright. But it is being set to true in a FileReader's onload method inside method_1. Please take a look at my re-edited code @RocketHazmat , matt burland

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the scope in which you're setting `var_1` to true isn't what you want it to be:

```
CustomClass.prototype.method_1 = function(){

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(cropWidget) {
    this.var_1 = true;
  };
}
```

You're setting `var_` to `true` in a callback, and the value of `this` in the callback is **not** the same as in `method_1`.

You could use the `self = this` idiom to fix this:

```
CustomClass.prototype.method_1 = function(){
  // "this" here refers to the CustomClass instance,
  // so let's store it in "self" so we can use it in the callback
  var self = this; 

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(cropWidget) {
    // "this" here will not be the CustomClass instance, 
    // so we refer to the "self" variable from above.
    self.var_1 = true;
  };
}
```

That should solve your problem, though there is still a potential timing issue: if `method_2` is called before the `FileReader` fires its `onload` event, `var_1` won't yet be set to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

> this.var_1 is false, and not true as it should be.

That's likely because you do not refer to the same object. Your event handler `function(){
var customObj = new CustomClass(…);
}` creates an instance and assigns it to a *local variable*. It will get garbage-collected once the function is ran.

> IMO javascript is pass by reference, so that variable value should have been set to true in it's original place.

No, javascript is always pass-by-value. Yet, when you are passing objects, you are actually passing values that reference the object so there will be a lot of variables referencing the same "shared" object.

Comment: i made some edits, please re-read my question to get the edits,

Comment: Please show in your code the actual nesting of the functions (as @Rocket requested), it makes a huge difference.